# MOSS 2007 central administration - cannot connect to the configuration database

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am unable to access Sharepoint Central Administration.

I installed MOSS 2007 successfully on Windows Server 2008 (IIS7 and SQL Server 2005), I launched the admin and got "Cannot connect to the configuration database" error.

Application pool is using NetworkService account which has access to SQL Server.

I can access the configuration databases through SQL Management Studio. SQL server is on the same machine.

Any help, suggestions on how to solve the problem? I am very new to SharePoint.

Comment: You will get much better answers in serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running the SharePoint Products and Technologies configuration wizard again to see if that highlights what the issue might be.